Android Studio app installs and opens when connected but not when disconnected
I made an app, and I can install it on my phone and run it by clicking run in Android Studio, but I can't open the app without Android Studio. When I unplug my phone and close the app, I no longer have any way to access the app. It does not appear in the app list, but it does appear with the installed apps in Files. I can see the app info through Files, but I am not given the option to open from there (or settings, I believe it's the same screen); only uninstall and force stop. I am using a Pixel 8 Pro that is up to date.
In similar threads, the problem seemed to be the AndroidManifest not including
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
or
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />, but I have both of these, with android:exported="true".
Any ideas on what I can do to access my app?
Tried opening the app through all possible methods using just my phone, but nothing works or even shows the option to open the app.
Here is my manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.NFBeats"
    tools:targetApi="31">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>

EDIT: The solution was to create a separate intent filter for MAIN and LAUNCHER.

show your manifest

Please add your manifest code to understand the issue better.

I edited to show the manifest now

Split the current <intent-filter> element into two. One that only contains the MAIN action and the LAUNCHER category, and the other in the second <intent-filter>.

@Robert Thank you! This was the problem. I never knew that you needed separate intent filters.
